# Coefficient of Variation and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'd like to create a function with two arguments `(a, axis=0)` that computes the coefficient of variation of each column or row (2-dimensional array) and returns the index of the column or row with the maximum coefficient of variation.

I understand that `.argmax`returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis, but I'm unsure of how to proceed after that.

I'd like for the code to pass the following tests:

```
print(np.asscalar(arg_cvmax(b)) is 2)
print(np.asscalar(arg_cvmax(b,1)) is 0)
print(np.asscalar(arg_cvmax(b,axis=1)) is 0)
```

Comment: we need to see your `arg_cvmax` function and `b`

Comment: so far I've got: 
`def arg_cvmax(a, axis=0):
 cv = np.var(a) / np.mean(a)
 var = np.apply_along_axis(cv, axis=0, arr) 
return np.argmax(var)` although I'm not sure where 'b' comes into all this, especially within the test- given that we're trying to use `np.apply_along_axis` I'm assuming that I should define 'b' as an array of some sort? I'm just a little confused in that regard.

Comment: The function looks fine. You're going yo be passing `b` to the function so it must be defined somewhere above the tests.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right. oversight on my part! thanks for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use scipy to get the coefficent of variation and the use np.argmax to get the max row. You can use the axis argument to the variation function to compute max variation along row or column.

```
from scipy.stats import variation 

A = np.random.randn(10, 10)

# max variation along rows of A; 
# rows: axis=0, cols: axis=1

var = variation(A, axis=0)
idmax = np.argmax(var)
print(idmax)
```

Since the coefficent of variation is ratio of the standard deviation to the mean, you can avoid importing variation.

```
A = np.random.randn(10, 10)
cv =  lambda x: np.std(x) / np.mean(x)
var = np.apply_along_axis(cv, axis=0, arr=A)
idmax = np.argmax(var)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I've got some tests I need to pass including `print(np.asscalar(arg_cvmax(b)) is 2)` and it's giving me an error that says: `name 'b' is not defined`

Comment: The `np` approach in this answer is grossly incorrect in multiple ways. The [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation to the absolute value of the mean.

Answer (score 5):

About putonspectacles's answer.

Since the variation calculate the ratio of the biased standard deviation to the mean, it make sense to change the `np.var` in original lambda to `np.std`.

The non-stats import version should be like this:

```
A = np.random.randn(10, 10)
cv =  lambda x: np.std(x) / np.mean(x)
var = np.apply_along_axis(cv, axis=0, arr=A)
idmax = np.argmax(var)
```